TinyMCE - How to insert an image that is already on the server?
I am using the free version of TinyMCE.
I can insert and upload images. This works fine.
But if I want to use an image that is already on the server, I do not want to upload it again.
I would like to browse the pictures that are already on my webserver.
An older version of TinyMCE had 'imagemanager', which was perfect for this job.
Is there something like imagemanager for the free version of TinyMCE?
I already saw that there is a browse button for files and pictures on the Tinydrive, but this is not what I want.
I want an overview of the pictures that were already uploaded to the webserver.
